# facing error while changing the billing version

Tags: firebase, visual-studio, android-studio

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91M5u.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qtob.png)

i am facing error plz help me
here are the error

```
public boolean isSubscribedToSubscriptionItem(String sku) {
        if (skuListSubscriptionsList != null) {
            Purchase.PurchasesResult result = billingClient.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS);
            if (result.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && result.getPurchasesList() != null) {
                for (Purchase purchase :
                        result.getPurchasesList()) {
                    if (purchase.getSku().equals(sku)) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

when changing the version of billing from 3.0.3 to 6.0.1